# Alinear div a la derecha del padre

Tags: html, sass

necesito alinear a la derecha un div que tiene padre, el div que señalo a continuación se ajusta al finalizar el nombre del documento, pero necesito alinearlos a la derecha, adjunto el codigo que tengo por si me pueden ayudar, ademas de ello, tambien requiero que el bacground se ajuste a lo que es el contenido de la etiqueta padre

muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

css:

```css
.input-group-prepend-txt {
    padding-right: 125px;
    color: #000000;

    .accordion-right {
        justify-content: flex-end;
        display: flex;
        width: 150px;
        background-color: #e60d0d;
        align-items: center;
        position: absolute;

    
        .importancelevel{
            text-align: center;
            flex: 1;
        }
    
        .importance-color {
          width: 12px;
          height: 12px;
          border-radius: 50%;
        //   justify-self: flex-end;
          margin-left: 7px;
          margin-right: 7px;
        }
    
        .very-important {
          background-color: #c0504d;
        }
    
        .important {
          background-color: #da9694
        }
    
        .useful {
          background-color: #e6b8b7;
        }
    
        .optional {
          background-color: #fff;
        }
      }
    
  }
```

```html
<div class="input-group-prepend-txt d-flex col">
  <i class="guideline-icon type-{{ doc.type }}"> </i>
  <label for="doc-{{ doc.id }}">
       doc1
   </label>

  <div class="accordion-right d-flex">
    <strong class="importancelevel">very important</strong>
    <div class="importance-color {{doc.importance_level.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-')}}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hay multiples maneras de realizar lo que deseas, una de ellas es añadiendo una posición absoluta a tu clase .accordion-right y declarando su propiedad right en 0, de esta manera este se alineara a la derecha. Tambien es importante añadir una posición relativa a tu .input-group-prepend-txt para que sus hijos que tengan posición absoluta tomen como referencia para su posición a su padre más cercano con posición relativa, en caso contrario tu elemento se alineara a la derecha fuera de tu contendedor.

Ahora para centrar tu elemento verticalmente debes agregarle la propiedad top y bottom en 0 para que se que este se centre correctamente, al igual que su asignarle su margen en automatico y su altura en fit-content o establecerla en px ya que si esto no se realiza tu elemento ocupara la altura de su padre relativo.

```
.input-group-prepend-txt {
    padding-right: 125px;
    color: #000000;
    position: relative;
}

.accordion-right {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    display: flex;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #e60d0d;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    margin:auto;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: fit-content;
}
```

Aqui dejo tu código editado para que realizas las pruebas necesarias, le he añadido a tu .input-group-prepend-txt un height en pixeles y un color de fondo para notar la alineación vertical del elemento absoluto.

```css
.input-group-prepend-txt {
  padding-right: 125px;
  color: #000000;
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.accordion-right {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #e60d0d;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  height: fit-content;
}

.importancelevel {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.importance-color {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  //   justify-self: flex-end;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

.very-important {
  background-color: #c0504d;
}

.important {
  background-color: #da9694
}

.useful {
  background-color: #e6b8b7;
}

.optional {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group-prepend-txt d-flex col">
  <i class="guideline-icon type-{{ doc.type }}"> </i>
  <label for="doc-{{ doc.id }}">
       doc1
   </label>

  <div class="accordion-right d-flex">
    <strong class="importancelevel">very important</strong>
    <div class="importance-color {{doc.importance_level.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-')}}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Te recomiendo quitar una por una las propiedades que he agregado a tu css para que te entiendas mejor que función cumple cada una.

Saludos.

Comment: Mil gracias, ni te imaginas cuanto tiempo estuve intentando aplicar esos estilos :), que estés super bien